# Print every leaf path of a tree without recursive

Tags: algorithm

How do I print every leaf path of a tree without using recursion.

It is a tree, *NOT* a binary tree

```
struct node {
    int data
    std::vector<node*> children;
}
```

Print all the path from root to leaf, i.e. the following is the tree

- r:is the root node
- d, m, n are r's children
- x,y,z are d's children
- there is no child for m
- o, p are n's children

```
-------------root
------d         m          n
---x  y  z              o  p
```

The result should be:

```
root-d-x
root-d-y
root-d-z
root-m
root-n-o
root-n-p
```

I tried to use non-recursive way but failed.

Comment: I believe you can adjust non-recursive binary tree traversal for your case. The easiest implementation with minimum memory overhead would have a parent node pointer in `node`. See [nonRecursiveInOrderTraversal()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Answer (score 11):

```
public static void printAllPathToLeafNonRecursive(Node root) {

    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }

    Queue<Object> q = new LinkedList<Object>();
    q.add(root);
    q.add(root.data + "");

    while(!q.isEmpty()){

        Node head = (Node) q.poll();
        String headPath = (String) q.poll();

        if(head.isLeaf()){
            System.out.println(headPath);
            continue;
        }

        if(head.left!=null){
            String leftStr =  headPath + "->" + head.left.data;
            q.add(head.left);
            q.add(leftStr);
        }

        if(head.right!=null){
            String rightStr =  headPath + "->" + head.right.data;
            q.add(head.right);
            q.add(rightStr);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this print some nodes off the path as well?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc No it doesn't. See the way it uses the queue. It pushes the string to the queue as well, so it won't be written by off the path nodes. It's polled and appended appropriately :)

Comment: @smihael: For trees with more than 2 children, you can modify the above solution. Instead of inserting head.left & head.right, use : 

for(int i = 0; i < head.children[i]; i++) { 
    String si = headPath + "->" + head.children[i].data;
    q.add(head.children[i]);
    q.add(si);
}

Comment: A little late, but I want to point out that this is really slow because it copies a String for every node (not just the leaves). If N is the # nodes and K is the # leaves, the usual algorithm runs in O(KN) but this runs in O(N^2), which is a big difference on arbitrary non-binary trees

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Python solution based purely on pre-order iterative traversal using a stack. Prints both the paths and pathsums.

```
 class Stack(object): # just for reference
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []

    def push(self, b):
        self.a.append(b)

    def peek(self):
        return self.a[-1]

    def pop(self):
        return self.a.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.a) == 0

    def show(self):
        return self.a

 def paths(troot): # you should create your own Tree and supply the root
    current = troot
    s = Stack()
    s.push(current)
    s.push(str(current.key))
    s.push(current.key)

    while not s.isEmpty():
        pathsum = s.pop()
        path = s.pop()
        current = s.pop()

        if not current.left and not current.right:
            print 'path: %s, pathsum: %d' % (path, pathsum)

        if current.right:
            rightstr = path + "->" + str(current.right.key)
            rightpathsum = pathsum * 10 + current.right.key
            s.push(current.right)
            s.push(rightstr)
            s.push(rightpathsum)

        if current.left:
            leftstr = path + "->" + str(current.left.key)
            leftpathsum = pathsum * 10 + current.left.key
            s.push(current.left)
            s.push(leftstr)
            s.push(leftpathsum)
```

For example, for the following tree:

```
                          3                                                
                       /   \
                      /     \
                     /       \
                    /         \
                   /           \
                  /             \
                 /               \
                /                 \
              1                       7                        
           /   \                   /   \
          /     \                 /     \
         /       \               /       \
        /         \             /         \
        0           2           5           8            
     /   \       /   \       /   \       /   \
    /     \     /     \     /     \     /     \
   NUL   NUL   NUL   NUL     4     6   NUL     9
```

The output would be:

```
    >>> paths()
    path: 3->1->0, pathsum: 310
    path: 3->1->2, pathsum: 312
    path: 3->7->5->4, pathsum: 3754
    path: 3->7->5->6, pathsum: 3756
    path: 3->7->8->9, pathsum: 3789
```

Answer (score 2):

The strategy is simple.  Go down, right, then up.  At each point you know where to go next.

Keep a vector which is your current place in the tree.  Start it on the root.  And then in pseudocode:

```
while True:
    if not a leaf:
        current_place.push_back(0) // move down one
    else:
        print current path.
        while can't move right:
             if at root:
                 exit()
             current_place.pop_back() //move up one
        current_place[-1] += 1
```

Those operations will require function calls.  But they are function calls with loops, not recursion, so it is not recursive.

Comment: Basically, you need to use explicit stack operations to mimic the behavior of a recursive function.

Comment: @Groo, exactly.  I thought about using a queue, but that would have not put things in the requested order.

Comment: This algorithm (although missing some detail) is the better option.

Answer (score 1):

In the end,it's just a graph.  There are different types of graph traversals. Just use dfs  with a stack,and print nodes from which you don't have forward edges.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void RoottoPathPrint(BinaryTreeNode root) {
    Stack<Object> stack = new Stack<Object>();
    if (root == null)
        return;
    stack.push(root.getData() + "");
    stack.push(root);
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        BinaryTreeNode temp = (BinaryTreeNode) stack.pop();
        String path = (String) stack.pop();

        if (temp.getRight() != null) {
            stack.push(path + temp.getRight().getData());
            stack.push(temp.getRight());
        }
        if (temp.getLeft() != null) {
            stack.push(path + temp.getLeft().getData());
            stack.push(temp.getLeft());
        }
        if (temp.getLeft() == null && temp.getRight() == null) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea being to keep track of both the path and the nodes in a single stack as we traverse down the tree. The Object stack takes care of that.
Hope that helped !!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void rootToLeaf(BSTNode root){
    Stack<Map<BSTNode,ArrayList<Integer>>> tmpStack = new Stack<Map<BSTNode,ArrayList<Integer>>>();
    Map<BSTNode,ArrayList<Integer>> tmpMap = new HashMap<BSTNode,ArrayList<Integer>>();
    //List<Integer> tmp_arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> tmpList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    tmpList.add(root.data);
    tmpMap.put(root, tmpList);
    tmpStack.push(tmpMap);
    while(!tmpStack.isEmpty()){
        Map<BSTNode,ArrayList<Integer>> temp_map = tmpStack.pop();
        for(BSTNode node : temp_map.keySet()){
            if(node.getLeft()==null && node.getRight()==null){
                for(int i: temp_map.get(node)){
                    System.out.print(i+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            if(node.getRight()!=null){
                ArrayList<Integer> tmp_List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int i: temp_map.get(node)){
                    tmp_List.add(i);
                }
                tmp_List.add(node.getRight().getData());
                Map<BSTNode,ArrayList<Integer>> tmphashMap = new HashMap<BSTNode,ArrayList<Integer>>();
                tmphashMap.put(node.getRight(), tmp_List);
                tmpStack.push(tmphashMap);
            }
            if(node.getLeft()!=null){
                ArrayList<Integer> tmp_List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int i: temp_map.get(node)){
                    tmp_List.add(i);
                }
                tmp_List.add(node.getLeft().getData());
                Map<BSTNode,ArrayList<Integer>> tmphashMap = new HashMap<BSTNode,ArrayList<Integer>>();
                tmphashMap.put(node.getLeft(), tmp_List);
                tmpStack.push(tmphashMap);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For n-ary tree - DFS and BFS based Path, Sum

```
                            100     
                      /    /   \     \
                    1     2     3     4
   /   /   /   /   /                /   \   
 10   11  12  13  14              40    41 
                                 / \
                              400  401


public void traverseDFS(Node root) {
    Stack<Node> s = new Stack<Node>();
    Stack<String> sPath = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Integer> sSum = new Stack<>();
    s.push(root);   sPath.push(root.Id + "");   sSum.push(root.Id);

    while (!s.isEmpty()) {
      // Pop out
      Node head = s.pop();    String headPath = sPath.pop();    Integer headSum = sSum.pop();
      if(head.children == null || head.children.isEmpty()){ //Leaf
        System.out.println(headPath + "(" + headSum+")");
        continue;
      }
      for(Node child : head.children) {
        String path = headPath + "->" + child.Id;
        Integer sum = headSum + child.Id;
        // Push on stack
        s.push(child);    sPath.push(path);   sSum.push(sum);
      }
    }
  }

public static void traverseBFS(Node root) {

    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
    Queue<String> qPath = new LinkedList<>();
    Queue<Integer> qSum = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(root);  qPath.add(root.Id + "");  qSum.add(root.Id);

    while(!q.isEmpty()){
      // Poll the q
      Node head = q.poll();   String headPath = qPath.poll();   Integer headSum = qSum.poll();
      if(head.children == null || head.children.isEmpty()){ //Leaf
        System.out.println(headPath + "(" + headSum+")");
        continue;
      }
      for(Node child : head.children) {
        String path = headPath + "->" + child.Id;
        Integer sum = headSum + child.Id;
        // Add to the q
        q.add(child);   qPath.add(path);    qSum.add(sum);
      }
    }
  }

class Node {
  int Id;
  String Data;
  Node Parent;
  ArrayList<Node> children;

  public Node(int id, String data) {
    Id = id;
    Data = data;
  }
}
```

Output

```
-----------Depth FS-------------
100->4->41(145)
100->4->40->401(545)
100->4->40->400(544)
100->3(103)
100->2(102)
100->1->14(115)
100->1->13(114)
100->1->12(113)
100->1->11(112)
100->1->10(111)
-----------BFS-------------
100->2(102)
100->3(103)
100->1->10(111)
100->1->11(112)
100->1->12(113)
100->1->13(114)
100->1->14(115)
100->4->41(145)
100->4->40->400(544)
100->4->40->401(545)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void allPathsToLeafNodesWithPreOrderDFS() {
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<> ();
    stack.push (root);
    List<Deque<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<> ();

    while (!stack.isEmpty ()) {
        Node pop = stack.pop ();
        System.out.print (" " + pop.data);
        if (pop.isLeaf ()) {
            Deque<Integer> path = new ArrayDeque<> ();
            Node current = pop;
            while (current != null) {
                path.add (current.data);
                current = current.parent;
            }
            paths.add (path);
        }
        if (pop.right != null) {
            pop.right.parent = pop;
            stack.push (pop.right);
        }
        if (pop.left != null) {
            pop.left.parent = pop;
            stack.push (pop.left);
        }
    }
    System.out.println ("paths = " + paths);
}

public void allPathsToLeafNodesWithInOrderDFS() {
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<> ();
    List<Deque<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<> ();
    Node current = root;

    while (!stack.isEmpty () || current != null) {
        if (current != null) {
            stack.push (current);
            if (current.left != null) current.left.parent = current;
            current = current.left;
        } else {
            Node pop = stack.pop ();
            System.out.println (" " + pop.data);
            if (pop.isLeaf ()) {
                Deque<Integer> path = new ArrayDeque<> ();
                Node now = pop;
                while (now != null) {
                    path.add (now.data);
                    now = now.parent;
                }
                paths.add (path);
            }
            current = pop.right;
            if (pop.right != null) pop.right.parent = pop;
        }

    }
    System.out.println ("paths = " + paths);
}

public void allPathsToLeafNodesWithBFS (){
    List<Deque<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<> ();
    Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<> ();
    queue.add (root);
    while (!queue.isEmpty ()){
        Node poll = queue.poll ();
        System.out.println ("poll = " + poll);
        if (poll.isLeaf ()){
            Deque<Integer> path = new ArrayDeque<> ();
            Node current = poll;
            while (current != null){
                path.add (current.data);
                current = current.parent;
            }
            paths.add (path);
        }
        if(poll.left != null) {
            poll.left.parent = poll;
            queue.add (poll.left);
        }
        if(poll.right != null) {
            poll.right.parent = poll;
            queue.add (poll.right);
        }
    }
    System.out.println ("paths = " + paths);
}
```